# What is the most efficient way to achieve "End Game" in Secret of the Magic Crystals?

Tags: secret-of-the-magic-crystals

In "Secret of the Magic Crystals", [the hardest achievement](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/SecretMagicCrystal/achievements) (0.7% completed) is called "End Game" and is described by the following sentence:

> By the power of the Magic Crystals I was able to bring this Story to a Happy Ending!

After some research on the Internet, I understand this achievement consists in breeding five *different* level 5 magical horses for the quest to uncover the secret of the magic crystals, one of each type:

> 1. Unicorn: The grace and beauty of this horse is one of a kind.
> 2. Pegasus: The Ancestors of this Colt were unique racehorses.
> 3. Fire Steed: This colts ancestors were fearless and wild by nature.
> 4. Ice Steed: Mountain People Bred this kind of muscular horse.
> 5. Demon Steed: People of forgotten civilizations passed on the secrets
>      of breeding this type of horse.

However, the stable contains only six different slots. And to get a level 5 horse, I need two level 4 horses and one empty slot, which would suggest I need to sell the level 5 horses, based on [the pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

So what is the most efficient way to achieve "End Game" in Secret of the Magic Crystals?

Comment: I have never played the game, but based just on your description, do you need all of the horses at the same time to get the achievement?

Comment: This, I don't know yet. I could not find the information on the Internet. It is possible to sell a horse, which would make the achievement more likely to be achieved.

Comment: Then it means one has to repeat five times the same sequence of actions in order to breed five times a level 5 horse from scratch. Breeding a level 5 horse needs to be optimized.

Comment: Does breeding immediately require a new stall? Or can you breed -> sell father before baby is born?

Comment: No, you need a new stall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either gathering the second crystal or acquiring your second level five horse to unlock more space in your stable. I'll confirm which later.

Answer (score 0):

When your well is at level 5 (max upgrade), it will automatically create a new, empty stall every time you breed a level 5 horse. This way you can keep all your level 5 horses.